# Restart nodejs script after some time depending on the error

Tags: node.js

I have a nodejs script which crashes sometimes. I have used forever to restart the script upon crashing. Now there is a problem, some errors make it so that I need to wait a specific time before I can restart the script. How would I go about handling the different errors so that the script gets instantly restarted on every crash except the one where I Need to wait for 30 minutes.

Comment: What kind of error msg do you get?

Comment: Can you detect the error which needs 30mn of waiting before it arrives ? If yes, you can have another script managing the forever rules for your main script and which will wait the 30mn and then launch the main script again.

Comment: I get an error object and I can identifiy on which error I have to wait. How would I go about managing a script from another script, and handling errors then.

Comment: try something like [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) to run the node server

Comment: Try pm2 http://pm2.keymetrics.io